# Themeforest to Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, themes

This is my first time using an external HTML theme for a rails app. I have downloaded a theme from Themeforest. Of course it comes with tons of JS, CSS and images. I was wondering what workflow most of you guys use when integrating a theme into your rails app.

- Do you put all the downloaded assets in the public folder? Or do you put them in appropriate folders in app/assets and then fix the image urls etc.?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this question will get answers based on opinion, but you can try this gem to install static html for your application (not tested) . [install_theme gem](https://github.com/drnic/install_theme). For reference to use this gem read this blog
 `http://drnicwilliams.com/category/ruby/ruby-on-rails/page/2/` (If I put tuts in here my answer will full post)

For your question :

> Do you put all the downloaded assets in the public folder? Or do you put them in appropriate folders in app/assets and then fix the image urls etc.?

My workflow looks like :

1. Put css, js, image, font files to assests directory

   > ```
   > -assets
   >    - fonts
   >    - images
   >    - javascripts
   >    - stylesheets
   > ```
2. Editing url image, url font in css files and js files.

   If I use extention `css.erb` for css file, url image, url font should edit looks like :

   image :

   > ```
   > background-image:url(<%= asset_path 'bg.png' %>);
   > ```

   font :

   > ```
   > @font-face {
   >     font-family: namefonts;
   >     src: url('<%= asset_path('namefonts.eot') %>');
   >     src: url('<%= asset_path('namefontsd41d.eot') %>?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), 
   >        url('<%= asset_path('namefonts.woff') %>') format('woff'), 
   >        url('<%= asset_path('namefonts.ttf') %>') format('truetype'), 
   >        url('<%= asset_path('namefonts.svg') %>#icons') format('svg');
   >     font-weight: 400;
   >     font-style: normal;
   > }
   > ```

   If I use extention `css.scss`

   image :

   > ```
   > background : image-url("bg.png")
   > ```

   font :

   > ```
   > @font-face {
   > font-family:'namefonts';
   > src:font-url('namefonts.eot');
   > src:font-url('namefonts.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
   >
   >  ...
   > }
   > ```
3. Choose html structure to layout template (head tag, header, navbar, sidebar footer), partial template (contents, forms etc) - If I use `html.erb`

   > ```
   > -views
   >    - layouts
   >    - partials
   >      - form
   >      - index
   > ```

   Coding Links to Assets

   > ```
   > <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all" %>
   > <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
   > ```
4. Editing image tag, url tag, form tag etc to conform with rails template (erb file)

   **image tag**

   example in html

   > ```
   > <img src="images/rails.png" class="theclass"/>
   > ```

   change to

   > ```
   > <%= image_tag "rails.png", :class => 'theclass' %>
   > ```

   **link tag**

   example in html

   > ```
   > <a href="index.html">Home</a>
   > ```

   change to

   > ```
   > <%= link_to "Home", root_path %>
   > ```

   **form tag** you can read [this](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html)

   > ```
   > <%= form_tag("action", method: "post") do %>
   >  <%= label_tag(:q, "Label for:") %>
   >  <%= text_field_tag(:q) %>
   >  <%= submit_tag("Save") %>
   > <% end %>
   > ```
5. Editing any file to conform with rails

   You can read this

   - [Assets Pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)
   - [Layouts and Rendering in Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html)
   - [Form Helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html)
6. Updating the asset pipeline

   The fix is pretty simple. Open your project's config file, located at `config/application.rb` and add the following line within your Application class:

   > ```
   > config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "fonts")
   > config.assets.precompile += %w( .svg .eot .woff .ttf )
   > ```

Comment: Please I want to know what is point 4 exactly is talking about

Comment: @AymanSalah : point 4 is converting html tag (image tag, link tag, form tag) to rails template. I have updated for point 4.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I now understand it a bit more. But i still have questions.. I now need to give my forms css styling for example i need to have the button from the theme instead of the normal f.submit style how can i achieve that

Comment: You can add class to it, example `<%= f.submit "Sign up", :class => "theclass" %>`

Comment: recently used this regex in sublime text to help. Find: `['"]/assets(.*?/)(.*?\..*?)['"]` replace with `<%= asset_path '\2' %>`

Answer (score 5):

> Do you put all the downloaded assets in the public folder? Or do you
>   put them in appropriate folders in app/assets and then fix the image
>   urls etc.?

The bottom line is  if you're going to do the job, *do it right*

To do this, I would personally integrate the theme from the ground-up. Firstly, by changing the various `layouts` you may have (to accommodate the classes & styling of the theme), and then working through each part of the system to style it accordingly.

--

**Assets**

In order to render the `assets` correctly, I would most certainly include them in the `app/assets` folder, rather than `public/____`. Reason being they are part of the general assets of the application, and need to be kept within the [asset pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html).

I would therefore basically do 3 things:

> - Put the `images` from the theme into `app/assets/images`
> - Put the `stylesheets` from the theme into `app/assets/stylesheets`
> - Put the `javascripts` from the theme into `app/assets/javascripts`

I would then go through the application & work to get the styling to work correctly (starting with the `layout` as mentioned).

I think it's important to point out that in order to achieve the best results, you will be best doing things right -- sitting down and working through the styling properly.

Comment: Thanks. I needed someone to tell me that yes, it can be done with asset pipeline and there are others who take the time to do it that way. It took nearly two days, but finally I have my layouts working. Thanks!

Comment: No problem! All the best stuff takes time - you can't get away from it. If you want to do the job properly, invest the time to do so :)

Answer (score 0):

here's my workflow:

I usually structure my assets like this (say it's an admin template and theme files are in sass)

```
/app
  /assets
    /stylesheets
      /admin
        _modal.scss
        _reset.scss
        _button.scss
        ....
      /vendor
        /bootstrap
          bootstrap.min.css
        /font-awesome
        ....

      admin.scss.scss
```

inside **admin.css.scss**

```
@import 'vendor/bootstrap/bootstrap';
@import 'admin/modal';
@import 'admin/reset';
@import 'admin/button';
```

I usually do the same with javascript

as for the html's

I usually do render per section (one partial for the topbar, sidebar etc..)

I usually place them in

```
/app
  /views
    /partials
```

so I'm calling

```
<%=render '/partials/topbar'%>
```

Hope this helps