# Rails & themeforest integration issue, getting routing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, themes

I am trying to integrate themeforest template into Rails app. I am getting a routing error

> ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff"):

I actually followed the solution given in this [Themeforest to Rails App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24051008/themeforest-to-rails-app)

The structure is  as

> `-assets
>      - fonts
>      - images
>      - javascripts
>      - stylesheets`

My font-awesome.css file has

> `@font-face {
>     font-family: 'FontAwesome';
>     src: url('fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.2.0');
>     src: url('fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.2.0') format('embedded-opentype'), url('fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.2.0') format('woff'), url('fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.2.0') format('truetype'), url('fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.2.0#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
>     font-weight: normal;
>     font-style: normal;
>   }`

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Not sure - but I see from the code and error your CSS file is getting font styles from a file called fonts/fontawesome-webfont
but
there is no such file is in your project?

You might want to download and put those under assets/fonts directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is how you use path, you can change it to

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    src: asset-url('fontawesome-webfont.eot');
    src: asset-url('fontawesome-webfont.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
           asset-url('fontawesome-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
           asset-url('fontawesome-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
           asset-url('fontawesome-webfont.svg#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```